# OSMnx - tags missing in graph edges

Tags: osmnx

I'm trying to detect all the streets in a city were bikes can ride. To do this I want to include the footways that include the tag `"bicycle":"yes"`, but I can't find it in the data downloaded with OSMnx.

For example the edge with id **45031879** as an xml downloaded directly from openstreetmap website appears like this:

```
<way id="45031879" visible="true" version="4" changeset="64616340" timestamp="2018-11-18T10:34:12Z" user="livmilan" uid="712033">
  <nd ref="571102337"/>
  ...
  <nd ref="1587102704"/>
  <tag k="bicycle" v="yes"/>    <=====
  <tag k="highway" v="footway"/>
</way>
```

But in the edges when downloaded with OSMnx with command `graph = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='all'))` it appears like this:

```
{'osmid': 45031879, 'highway': 'footway', 'oneway': False, 'length': 22.818, 'geometry': <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x00000170F3F112C8>}
```

It appears that the bicycle information went lost. Is there a way to download the additional tags with osmnx?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

[Configure](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils.config) the `useful_tags_way` setting to add additional OSM way tags to retain as graph edge attributes:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True,
          useful_tags_way = ox.settings.useful_tags_way + ['bicycle'])

place = 'Berkeley, CA, USA'
G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='bike')
edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False)
'bicycle' in edges.columns #True
```