# How to add bike-able walking segments in "bike" network type in osmnx?

Tags: networkx, openstreetmap, osmnx

I used the following code to import the bike network from osmnx.

```
place = "Nashville, USA"
G0 = ox.graph_from_address(place, distance=1000, simplify=True, network_type='bike')

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G0);
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I am working with GPS trace data of bicycling, which has points on the Pedestrian bridge 
[image: pointed by red circle in the image]). 
But osmnx doesn't download such segments if I pass "bike" as network type.

Is there any way to download such bike-able walking segments? Also, is there any quick way to clean up such a network?

Comment: I have similar issue, where osmx looses information about "bike"=" yes"bon pedestrian roads. Apoarently, many tags are not considered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841035/osmnx-tags-missing-in-graph-edges

Comment: Fixed this issue. [https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/389](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`

Answer (score 0):

This was answered [elsewhere](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/389) but I'll copy the answer here too in case anyone lands here while searching for similar information.

> The problem is that the bridge (as currently digitized) doesn't connect to any other bikeable infrastructure on either end, so the graph is disconnected. Using retain_all=True keeps all components of the disconnected graph.