# how to get tags for hov and toll using osmnx

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I would like to ask how to get values for the hov (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:hov) tag and the toll tag (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:toll) using osmnx.

The following is my codes:

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from pandas import Series, DataFrame

cf = '["highway"~"motorway"]'

G = ox.graph_from_place("Los Angeles County, California, USA", network_type="drive", custom_filter=cf)

G = ox.add_edge_bearings(G)

gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False)
df=pd.DataFrame(gdf_edges).reset_index()
df.columns
```

The following is the output:

[image]

You can see that there is no column name called hov or toll. Therefore, I would like to ask how I could know whether a segment of the freeway (i.e. edge) is hov or toll-road. Thank you.

Thanks to @gboeing's reply, I can add these two tags using the following codes:

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from pandas import Series, DataFrame

ox.settings.useful_tags_way += ["hov"]
ox.settings.useful_tags_way += ["toll"]

cf = '["highway"~"motorway"]'

G = ox.graph_from_place("Los Angeles County, California, USA", network_type="drive", custom_filter=cf)

G = ox.add_edge_bearings(G)

gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False)
df=pd.DataFrame(gdf_edges).reset_index()
df.columns
```

The following is the output:
[image]

Comment: Use the `useful_tags_way` setting in the `settings` module. See the docs: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-reference.html#module-osmnx.settings

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/62180881/7321942